# Excel 2nd axis categorical data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2019

I need a 2-axis Excel chart. Primary axis is US Deficit by year - this would be a bar chart w/ both positive and negative value ranges in time series from 1940-2019. 2nd axis would be a binary categorical value - party in power. I want the "foreground to be the deficit bar lines, but a "shadow" background color or other symbol that vertical stripes the presidential administration years in a colored background for party. Imagine different colored backround vertical bands (full length bars) for the Nixon-Ford years vs the Carter years, etc. How would i do this? Tks.

Comment: A combo chart would be my starting point. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will need to insert columns for each party in power and fill them in like this:

[image]

2. Insert a combo chart setup like this:

[image]

3. Right-click on the left hand axis and choose "Format Axis" from the menu
   [image]
4. Set the Maximum to `1`

[image]

5. Under Labels, Choose "none"

[image]

6. Right click on one of the series for party and choose "Format Data Series"

[image]

7. Set the Gap Width to 0%

[image]

8. For both series, I also recommend you sent the transparency to 70% or so (this will allows lines to show up underneath them)

[image]

9. pick a nice contrasting colour for the bars of the deficit

You chart should now look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Fabulous. Thanks so much.

Comment: If that answers your question, your should mark it as correct, that way others will know it has been resolved